# Drop-off library takes default content type

Tags: content-type, content-organizer

I'm having an issue trying to upload multiple documents to a library using the Content Organizer.

Problem is that when I upload several files to a library which has a Content Type 'A' all the files go to the Drop-Off library. So far it's OK but when I check the content type of the documents they take the default content type of the drop-off library (for example 'B') and that's really annoying. They should take the 'A' CT.

Any help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you describe is as expected. The reason is that you must have setup rules for various other content types (assume those are already in place) - which should have been added to the library also in the process.

Ideally items should not be dropped directly there but rather be sent by the system when items are NOT matching any of the rules setup (as end-users try to upload files somewhere and do not select enough attributes, including content type for the system to successfully route elsewhere), moment at which designated administrator will receive notifications to properly setup content type and other properties.

Make some properties mandatory to avoid people getting away easy with not classifying content.